# Turning a string into a Matrix in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following code:

```
My_String = "{i},{j},{i,j}" # which is a line
```

I want to convert that into a matrix where `{i,j}` is a column and `{i}` and `{j}` are rows. I know how to do naming for the columns and rows but dont know how to make such a matrix. I dont need an exact answer but I just need guidance. If anyone can help me that would be great.

Comment: Can you add a more concrete example of your requirement. Specifically with multiple lines.

Comment: Yes. My String = {1},{2},{1,2} which is a line where 1 and 2 are vertices of the line and {1,2} is the edge. I want an incident matrix where {1} and {2} are rows in  a matrix and {1,2} is a column.                 {i,j}
          i    0    0      1
          j    0    0      1

Comment: @Anoop  That last line I wrote was supposed to be input as a matrix. It just wrote it like a sentence..

Comment: My String = {1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{1,3} // MatrixForm

 {ij} {jk} {ik} 
i 1 0 0 
j 1 0 0  
k 0 0 0

Answer (score 0):

Who don't you use a dictionary? According to your description the single elements in brackets are the vertex when are finished these one, you put edges in brackets after them.

Before proceeding I need to change a little your representation. Each edge should be represented in this way: "{1-2}" which means that there is a connection between the vertex "1" and the vertex "2".

So I will do something like this:

1. Split the line using the comma. You will get an array of element
2. Loop through this array. If the element doesn't contain an "-" you need to create an empy entry in your dictionary with the vertex label as a key; otherwise you should get the vertexes' label from the edge's representation (you can use regex) and insert a new entry in the dictionary whose key is the first vertex of the edge and whose value is the second vertex's label.

Using this approach you will get a dictionary that will represent an adjacency matrix of the defined graph.